# Quarkus JPA/Hibernate persist() not doing SQL insert, no error indicator

Tags: hibernate, jpa, insert, quarkus, persist

Using Quarkus for a small REST project. The main entity is a Bookmark, which has @Entity, @Id and so on annotations. The REST service methods directly delegate to a data service or DAO. The DAO's 4 or so GET methods all work fine, fetching Bookmarks that are loaded from `import.sql`. The one POST method executes with no error but Hibernate doesn't execute the SQL insert, though it does call hibernate_sequence to get the primary key for the should-be-inserted object, and does set the new pkey on the in-memory object (all researched with temporary print statements, shown below). Also, prePersist method on the entity gets called but postPersist on same class does not.

Happens on both H2 and PostgreSQL.

Here is an excerpt from the REST service:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class BookmarksDaoJpa implements BookmarksService {

    @Inject EntityManager em;

    public List<Topic> topics() {
        return em.createQuery("from Topic t order by t.description", Topic.class).getResultList();
    }

    // Other GET methods omitted, they work

    // Inserts into database, returns new pkey #
    @Transactional(value= Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
    public long postBookmark(Bookmark bookmark) throws Exception {
        if (bookmark.getId() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Persisting " + bookmark);
            em.persist(bookmark);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Merging " + bookmark);
            em.merge(bookmark);
        }
        // em.flush();
        System.out.println("bookmark.getId() = " + bookmark.getId());
        return bookmark.getId();
    }
```

Here is the output from the Quarkus run, showing what happens when I POST an entity:

```
Hibernate: insert into bookmark(id, topic_id, url, text) values(4, 'pol', 'http://huff.puff.com', 'Breaking: Another politician told the truth!')
__  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______ 
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/ 
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \   
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/   
2023-03-01 08:09:28,465 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) bookmarks.rest 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.16.3.Final) started in 3.514s. Listening on: http://localhost:8086

2023-03-01 08:09:28,467 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2023-03-01 08:09:28,468 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, jdbc-h2, jdbc-postgresql, narayana-jta, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]
BookmarksResource.onBeginTransaction: TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a82a2d:142f:63ff4e97:0 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING >
Persisting Bookmark(#0, topic tech, url https://dev/null, text Puff the fractal dragon)
Bookmark.prePersist: id = 0
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
bookmark.getId() = 10
BookmarksResource.onBeforeEndTransaction
2023-03-01 08:09:43,238 WARN  [io.agr.pool] (executor-thread-0) Datasource '<default>': Closing open connection prior to commit
BookmarksResource.onAfterEndTransaction
```

**Full code** including test script is at https://github.com/IanDarwin/bookmarks-backend

So the question is: **WHY is Hibernate giving up mid-transaction but not throwing an exception?**

A side issue, probably related: The tracing from the @Observes Transaction methods show the transaction is in effect up until the end of the method. Yet if I uncomment the em.flush() in the middle, it says there is no transaction in effect.

I've used JPA multiple times and persist normally does persist, so I assume I've made some booboo, but I can't see it after staring at this for far too long. As this is only my 2nd Quarkus app, I am not sure if my problem is with Quarkus or with JPA. I have scrutinized the configs of both and, with the lack of any output at all (either an SQL trace or an error message), it is difficult to know where to look. TIA if you can point it out.

Comment: Replacing `@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)` with a simple `@Transactional` solve the problem? Or remove event observers just to be sure that they are not interfer in some way

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Thanks so much for answering but, alas, neither solves the problem. I only tried @Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW) since REQUIRED, which is the default on "a simple @Transactional", wasn't working. So I'm going to edit the main post back to REQURED. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grrr. My persistence.xml didn't specify `transaction-type="JTA"` and on Quarkus it apparently defaults to `RESOURCE-LOCAL` and then fails silently.

Obviously it should report an error, but it doesn't.